# .NET Core - UnauthorizedObjectResult added \" in ExtraDetail message

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I'm building a WebAPI with .netcoreapp 3.1 and I just want to return the default UnauthorizedObjectResult response with a nicely formatted ExtraDetail message - but for some reasons it keeps automatically adding escaped quotation marks (\") in there.

In my Task<IActionResult> ExecuteAsync method I'm returning the [UnauthorizedObjectResult(Object) constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.unauthorizedobjectresult.-ctor?view=aspnetcore-5.0#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Mvc_UnauthorizedObjectResult__ctor_System_Object_) with a simple string input:

```
if (loginFailed)
{
    return new UnauthorizedObjectResult("Login failed.");
}
```

It works fine returning 401 error code with the following JSON response body - except for the added escaped quotation marks in the "ExtraDetail" field value:

```
{
  "Result": {
    "ResultCode": "Failure",
    "Message": {
      "Errors": [
        {
          "Code": "1000",
          "System": "webapi.v1",
          "Timestamp": "2021-05-04T05:15:05.9855075Z",
          "Description": "A Unknown Technical Error occurred",
          "ExtraDetail": "\"Login failed.\""
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I tried several different ways to insert the string into the UnauthorizedObjectResult constructor but it keeps showing the extra \" no matter what I did.

Also this is a secondary question but is there any way to change the content of the "Description" field?
I've Googled around and I can't seem to find a straighforward way to do this.

Comment: That constructor takes an `object` so my guess is the serializer is trying to insert the value as an object and serializes it funny. If you do something like `new UnauthorizedObjectResult(new { Message = "Login Failed"})` does it serialize better? Though note it'd be an object property and no longer a simple string

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions @pinkfloydx33, I tried it but it actually appears worse:
`"ExtraDetail": "{\r\n  \"message\": \"Login Failed\"\r\n}"` - it's interesting that it prints the curly bracket as well but inside the quotation marks... Any other ideas?

Comment: You've got some sort of double serialization happening. In both instances the returned object is serialized, and then that value is serialized again into the final form. It explains both outputs you are seeing, but I've no idea how to fix that